# Perl and MySQL Inserting an XML string causes error 2006 "server gone away"

Tags: mysql, xml, perl

I am trying to insert a XML string into this table:

> CREATE TABLE `producto_xml` (   `Id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL
>   DEFAULT '0',   `FechaDescarga` datetime NOT NULL,   `XML` longtext,
>   PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),   CONSTRAINT `producto_xml_ibfk_1` FOREIGN
>   KEY (`Id`) REFERENCES `producto` (`Id`) ON DELETE
>   CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED

And this is my script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use DBI;
use XML::LibXML;

my $xmlfilename = 'E:/localhost/erp/XMLs/TPT/BigFile.xml';

my $MyDB = 'XXXXX';
my $MyHOST = 'localhost';
my $MyUSR = 'XXXXX';
my $MyPASS = 'XXXXX';

my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:$MyDB:$MyHOST",$MyUSR,$MyPASS, { AutoCommit => 1, RaiseError => 0, PrintError => 0 } ) or &ErrHandle('MySQL: connecting to DB.');
$dbh->do('SET NAMES utf8');

my $max_allowed_packet = ((1024*1024)*15);#15 mb
$dbh ->do('SET @max_allowed_packet='.$max_allowed_packet); 

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc;
eval { $doc = $parser->parse_file($xmlfilename);};
if ($@){ &ErrHandle('XML Parser: Incorrect XML File');}

print 'File length: ' . length($doc->toString(0)) . "\n";

my $St = 'INSERT INTO producto_xml (XML, FechaDescarga, Id) VALUES (?,NOW(), ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE XML=VALUES(XML), FechaDescarga=NOW()';

my $Sth =$dbh->prepare($St);
$Sth->execute(
    $doc->toString(0)
    ,1780
);

if ($dbh->{'mysql_errno'} > 0) { &ErrHandle('MySQL: ' . $dbh->{'mysql_errno'} . ': ' . $dbh->{'mysql_error'}); }

print $dbh->{'mysql_insertid'} ."\n";
print $Sth->rows; 
exit;

sub ErrHandle {
    my $Err = shift;
    print 'ERROR: ' . $Err;
    exit;
}
```

The file "BigFile.xml" is about 1.2 Mb and I have this error no matter what i try:

```
File length: 1207951
ERROR: MySQL: 2006: MySQL server has gone away
```

I have tryed:

- Change Column Type to mediumtext, longblob, mediumblob
- Set max_allowed_packet to 15, 2, 1, 500 mb.

I have used the same script to insert files from about 300 Kb. without issues.

I will apreciate any help.

Enrique

Comment: Have you tried setting max_allowed_packet on the server, or only the client?

Comment: Hi, as I know, run the query "SET @max_allowed_packet=1515728" Works only for session.

Comment: You're right, the variable "max_allowed_packet" has to be configured in the file "my.ini". I've properly configured and working well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AKHolland hinted, `max_allowed_packet` should be set server-side.  Moreover, changing this parameter requires `mysqld` restart, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your message, I have set "max_allowed_packet" inside the "my.ini" file and is working.

Answer (score 0):

Information for any one how to change of `max_allowed_packet`

Change in the `my.ini/my.cnf` file. Include the single line under `[mysqld]` in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

now restart the `MySQL` service once you are done. You can see it's curent value in mysql like this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can read about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html